# Set width to an Angular2-modal window

Tags: angular, angular2-modal

I'm using `Angular2-modal` to create a modal with some content which some dynamic contents inside. This content is basically an image, but the dimensions are not always the same, but I know the dimensions when I create the modal, so how can I specify the dimensions of the modal?

```
this.modal.open(SnapshotCanvasModalComponent, overlayConfigFactory(context, BSModalContext));
```

being `context` a simple object with the image inside (`base64`).

I read that I can use modal-lg or modal-sm to set a class and then redefine those classes, but the dimensions in this case can´t be set by css but dynamically, as I don´t really know the dimensions of the image in advance.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: there are several models available. Can you please provide the link which model are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
this.modal.open(SnapshotCanvasModalComponent, overlayConfigFactory({ size: "lg"}, BSModalContext));
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to styles.css file:

```
 .modal-dialog {
    width: fit-content;
    margin: 0 auto;
 }
```

then, you can define width on the html content of your modal, and this will be the width of your modal.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to styles.css

```
.modal-lg {
  min-width: 900px;
  width: fit-content;
}
```

This way you can control a minimum width for a sandard modal or when the content is bigger, it adjusts. Also, its better to set the width on 'modal-lg' as thats more appropriate to set width on rather than the modal-dialog class.